# Converting an excel columns with each cell like a dictionary to multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, json-normalize

```py
# test.csv
co11,col2
a,"{'Country':'USA', 'Gender':'Male'}"
b,"{'Country':'China', 'Gender':'Female'}"

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

- I have a column in a csv file, with each cell containing a python dictionary like data structure.
- How should I convert this cell in the csv into two columns named Country and Gender using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `test.csv`

- *I have a column in a csv file*

```py
co11,col2
a,"{'Country':'USA', 'Gender':'Male'}"
b,"{'Country':'China', 'Gender':'Female'}"
```

### Code

- The dictionaries in the column will be read as strings unless they are converted, using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

  - Use the `converters` parameter in [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- Use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to convert the `dicts`, with `keys` as headers and `values` for rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# read the csv and convert string to dict
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'col2': literal_eval})

# display(df)
  co11                                      col2
0    a      {'Country': 'USA', 'Gender': 'Male'}
1    b  {'Country': 'China', 'Gender': 'Female'}

# unpack the dictionaries in col2 and join then as separate columns to df
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.col2))

# drop col2
df.drop(columns=['col2'], inplace=True)

# df
  co11 Country  Gender
0    a     USA    Male
1    b   China  Female
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reading CSV File:**
ast.literal_eval is needed or pd.read_csv will read dictionary as string

```
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('/data_with_dict.csv', converters={'dict_col': ast.literal_eval})
```

**Processing the dataframe that contains a dictionary:**

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'unk_col' : ['foo','bar'], 
                   'dict_col': [{'Country':'USA',   'Gender':'Male'}, 
                                {'Country':'China', 'Gender':'Female'}]})

# Convert dictionary to columns
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['dict_col']), df['dict_col'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

# Write to file
df.to_csv(''/data_no_dict.csv'', index=False)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  unk_col Country  Gender
0     foo     USA    Male
1     bar   China  Female
```